# Issue with export-csv no data?

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

In my report when I remove the export-csv portion the data is presented correctly onscreen, when I add in the export-csv no data is exported but the file is created. Below is my script along with what the data looks like when script is running (modified) of what the data looks like.

```
#Get all DHCP Servers
$ServerList = (Get-Content -Path "\\termserv\DHCPServers.txt")
foreach ($server in $serverlist)
{
#Get the scopes from each serve
     Get-DHCPServerv4Scope -ComputerName $server | select ScopeID | 
#Get the lease information for each scope
     ForEach-Object {Get-DHCPServerv4Lease -ScopeId $_.ScopeId -ComputerName 
     $server -AllLeases  | 
        where {$_.AddressState -like "*Reservation"} | Select-Object 
        $server,ScopeId,IPAddress,HostName,ClientID,AddressState | Export-
        Csv "\\termserv\d$\term\User\Reservations1.csv"
   }
  }
```

What the data looks like when exported without export-csv

NOPEDH01     : 
ScopeId      : 000.11.2.3
IPAddress    : 111.22.3.444
HostName     : NOPE00112233
ClientID     : 00-11-22-33-44-55
AddressState : ActiveReservation

NOPEDH01     : 
ScopeId      : 000.11.2.3
IPAddress    : 111.22.3.445
HostName     : NOPE0011223344
ClientID     : 00-11-22-33-44-56
AddressState : ActiveReservation

Update: Tried that and still nothing, when I run a modified version of the script locally on my DH servers it functions correctly, but I'm looking at almost 100 DH servers in my environment, see below

```
Get-DHCPServerV4Scope | ForEach {

Get-DHCPServerv4Lease -ScopeID $_.ScopeID -AllLeases | where 
{$_.AddressState -like '*Reservation'}

} | Select-Object ScopeId,IPAddress,HostName,ClientID,AddressState | Export-
Csv "\\termserv\d$\term\$($env:COMPUTERNAME)-Reservations1.csv" -
NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code you are using `Export-Csv` within a `foreach-object`. Generally `Export-csv` creates a csv file with new data. If data is already present in the csv file then it will overwrite the existing data with new one.
So instead of using

```
Export-Csv "\\termserv\d$\term\User\Reservations1.csv"
```

You cand use

```
Export-Csv "\\termserv\d$\term\User\Reservations1.csv" -Force -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

Here `-Append` will append the data in the csv file. Not overwrites.

Comment: You didn't add `-Append`

Comment: I did and got the error "The appended object does not have a property that corresponds to the following column: GJKZDH01. To continue with mismatched properties, add the 
-Force parameter, and then retry the command."

Comment: The answer is in your error. Add `-Force` in the line.

Comment: No problem. :).

Answer (score 1):

This is a representation of what you are doing:

```
Foreach ($Server in $ServerList)
{
    Foreach ($Scope in $ScopeList)
    {
        $Data | Export-csv -Path FileName.csv
    }
}
```

In doing so you are exporting data `[(Total Servers) x (Total Scopes per server)]` times which is a lot of I/O operations. It is just a logistics issue. You could collect the entire information into a table object before exporting. But that decision is up to you and your particular business needs.

The real issue, however, is that you are doing the export into the same file which essentially over writes whatever you have written before without telling it not to. So only the last export remains which I suspect is somehow blank.

Try using the `-Append` switch when you export.

```
$Data | Export-csv -Path FileName.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Also I noticed you are using `$server` variable in the `select-object` cmdlet where you should only be using the object's property names and not variable names. I do not know if that returns anything as the cmdlet would not know what to do with it, which could also be contributing to the problem.

Comment: You could also troubleshoot it by sending it to a txt file using out-File instead of csv. csv assumes your data to be compliant with a certain object structure. txt file is not that prejudiced.